# Why is the public class name wrong?(Card Layout)

Tags: java, cardlayout

> The program doesn't work still after I fixed the selling error. It says in the console. "Error: Main method not found in class help.MyCardLayout, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application" I don't know what that means.

```
package help;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyCardLayout implements ItemListener {
    JPanel cards;
    final static String BUTTONPANEL1 = "Card1";
    final static String BUTTONPANEL2 = "Card2";

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane){
        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel();
        String comboBoxItems[] = { BUTTONPANEL1, BUTTONPANEL2 };
        JComboBox cb  = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);

        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 1"));

        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(new JButton("Button 2"));

       cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
       cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL1);
       cards.add(card2, BUTTONPANEL2);

       pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
       pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards,  (String) evt.getItem());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutDemo");
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setTitle("CardLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CardLayoutDemo demo = new CardLayoutDemo();
        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);



        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
 public void itemStateChange(ItemEvent evt) {
                           ^ d is missing
```

The name is `itemStateChanged` and not `itemStateChange`

Comment: Because you should know better than to answer a typo question.

Comment: The question is off-topic. You answering it is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelt `itemStateChanged()` as `itemStateChange()` (there's a `d` missing at the end):

```
public void itemStateChange(ItemEvent evt){
                           ↑ here
```